# Retrieving From and To from recording status callback

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I need to save outgoing call recording locally, in order to do that I need to get From and To for recording.

I am using this guide to create sample application: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart

The only difference is next handler in order to record call:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

     // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
     // if is a valid phone number
     const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';
     const dial = twiml.dial({
       callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
       record: 'record-from-ringing-dual',
       recordingStatusCallback: 'https://hooks.mydomain.com/twilio/recording'
     });
     dial[attr]({}, event.To);

     callback(null, twiml);
};
```

After call end I successfully receive notification:

```
{
    "AccountSid": "AC****",
    "CallSid": "CA****",
    "RecordingChannels": 2,
    "RecordingDuration": 24,
    "RecordingSid": "RE***",
    "RecordingSource": "DialVerb",
    "RecordingStatus": "completed",
    "RecordingUrl": "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/****"
}
```

However when I am receiving call and recording details using API, there is no From and To information:

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var call = CallResource.Fetch(
            pathAccountSid: accountSid,
            pathSid: "CA****"
);
//Console.WriteLine(call.From);

var recording = RecordingResource.Fetch(pathAccountSid: accountSid,
            pathSid: "RE****");
```

From Twilio console I've spotted this this call generated two records:
[image]

And I recording exist on Parent call, but From and To comes to child call.

And now, knowing the parent Id I can't fetch child call.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can fetch the child call using the parent call sid. You can use it as a filter on the [Calls list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#calls-list-resource). In C# that would look like:

```
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var calls = CallResource.Read(
        parentCallSid: parentCallSid,
        pathAccountSid: accountSid
    );
```